# Pass an instance via Context menu for QTableView and QTableWidget in PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qtableview, qtablewidget

Uh, okay, friends, now I'm trying to add "export to Excel" feature for every table in my app like this:

```
...
def update_exportable_tables(self, *window):
    """
    Please don't ask why, here 'I know what I'm doing'
    """
    if not window:
        window = self.window

    for obj in window.__dict__:
        objname = obj.title().lower()
        the_object_itself = window.__dict__[obj]

        if isinstance(the_object_itself, (QTableWidget, QTableView)):
            the_object_itself.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            the_object_itself.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.TableContextEvent)


def TableContextEvent(self, event):
    menu = QMenu()
    excelAction = menu.addAction(u"Export to Excel")
    excelAction.triggered.connect(self.export)
    action = menu.exec_(QCursor.pos())

def export(self):
    print 'Here I should do export'
...
```

Yeah, it works fine, but.... The question is ***how should I pass the clicked table instance*** to my export() function?

Comment: you can use variable to remeber "active" table. You can check what you have in `event` argument in `TableContextEvent`,

Comment: @furas The event is PyQt4.QtCore.QPoint(), nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways to solve this. Here's one way:

```
def update_exportable_tables(self):
    for widget in QtGui.qApp.allWidgets():
        if isinstance(widget, QTableView):
            widget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            widget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)

def showContextMenu(self, pos):
    table = self.sender()
    pos = table.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos)
    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    excelAction = menu.addAction("Export to Excel")
    if menu.exec_(pos) is excelAction:
        self.export(table)

def export(self, table):
    print 'Here I should do export:', table
```

(NB: `QTableWidget` is a subclass of `QTableView`).

Comment: Thanks for your help again! Works like a charm except only thing that menu appears at weird coordinates far away from actual click and ever outside of main window. How should I fix that glitch and close the issue? ^_^

Comment: fixed mouse position by:

    def showContextMenu(self, pos):
            pos = QCursor().pos()

Comment: @pmus. Yes, sorry - the `pos` needs to be mapped to global coordinates. Using `QCursor` isn't ideal because it won't give proper keyboard support. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to [Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot), I googled one way to do it.

```
if isinstance(the_object_itself, (QTableWidget, QTableView)):
    the_object_itself.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
    tricky = lambda: self.TableContextEvent(the_object_itself)
    the_object_itself.customContextMenuRequested.connect(tricky)
...

def TableContextEvent(self, table_instance):
    print table_instance
    #     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ And yes, we have it!
```

**upd1:** It's still wrong, due connecting to only one instance (only last table instance is passed everywhere)